# psql COPY TO CSV doubling up quotes

Tags: postgresql, csv, psql

I am exporting a Postgres table of mine to CSV, to be imported into neo4j.

Here is my SQL:

```
\COPY (SELECT * FROM articles) TO '/home/relay/code/wiki/arc.heolo.gy/articles.csv' WITH CSV header;
```

However, there is an issue: for my JSON column, which looks like this:
`["string", "string", "string"]`, the output CSV looks like this:
`[""string"", ""string"", ""string""]`. Notice the doubling up of quotes.

This doubled-double-quote scenario is tripping up the neo4j CSV import parser.

Any ideas how to avoid this?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the `create table` statement for `articles`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the output file in CSV, can you use `sed` in your workflow, or integrate an exec to bash?

```
sed 's/""//g' csv > new.csv
```

Or could you reformat to some tab scheme and combine `cut` with `awk` to clip the quotes.

Comment: This worked! But I can't quite tell why it doubled up quotes in the first place...